# Can't load file in android studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, textures, runtime-error

I am trying to load a simple .png file in android studio using libgdx but for some reason it can not find it and I have no idea why.

All the info I have is in this image:
[image]

To me it looks like everything is in order so I don't really know where to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your desktop run configuration and make sure the working directory is set to android/assets.